# On std::unordered_set: asking for a list of types having default hasher

Tags: c++, c++11

Where can I find a list of the types (built-in types and standard containers) having default hasher? (so that I don't need to write one when I use `unordered_set` of that type.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the list of specializations defined in the C++ standard [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). But you need not know these, the compiler will tell you if you need to provide your own hash function.

Comment: It seems that G++ (4.6.2) require the `operator()` to be a const member function. The link in this answer doesn't mention that. Is that specified in the standard?

Comment: I see no such requirement in **§17.6.3.4 Hash Requirements**. I will check later with newer versions of g++.

Comment: @updogliu checked on 4.6.3 and 4.8, and you are right, it requires a const operator().

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard would contain such a list. Rather than digging it up, here's a partial list:

- primitive types
- pointer types; `shared_ptr<T>` and `unique_ptr<T, D>`
- `std::basic_string<...>` specializations.
- `std::thread:id`
- `std::type_index`
- `std::error_code`

Most importantly, `pair`, `tuple` and `array` are *not* included. The crucial composer function, `hash_combine`, is not included in the standard library, but you should feel free to take the one from Boost.

Comment: Additionally `std::string` (and `std::(w/u16/u32)string`) should also be there.

Comment: I know you said it's a *"partial list"*, but just for the sake of completeness, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are also specialized.